# How to stream video in webpage?

Tags: java, video, streaming

Say suppose i am on my website and i want to stream live video which should be available to all users who view the webpage. How can this be done in Java? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/guide/RTPRealTime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you specifics (since i didn't have any opportunities to work with it), but you should take a look at Java Media Framework (JMF for short) http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/

It offers streaming support over the RTP and RTSP protocol (RFC 2326: Real Time Streaming Protocol)

Maybe somebody else can give you more details, but this seems to be the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) which supports a lot more codecs for decoding and encoding than JMF does.